# What is the difference between "blurry" and "blurred"?

Tags: differences, adjectives, past-participles

The two quotes below discuss the same topic.

> Terry's tortured season took a surreal twist on Tuesday when a **blurry** image resembling him appeared on cigarette packets in India. <sup>[GUARDIAN](http://www.guardian.co.uk/football/2012/jan/03/john-terry-anti-smoking-india?INTCMP=SRCH)</sup>
>
> A **blurred** picture closely resembling the 31-year-old appears above a "smoking kills" slogan. <sup>[CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2012/01/03/sport/football/football-john-terry-india/index.html)</sup>

The definition of *blurry* and *blurred* is very identical whereupon *blurred* has an extended definition. From OALD:

> [**blurry**](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/blurry):
> without a clear outline; not clear
>
> [**blurred**](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/blurred):
> 1 not clear; without a clear outline or shape
> 2 difficult to remember clearly
> 3 difficult to distinguish, so that differences are not clear

I think that *blurry* is a derivative of the noun *blur* while *blurred* stems from the verb *blur*. But I wonder why there exists two forms. I tried to find other words where derivatives of both noun and verb with seemingly the same meaning exists to compare their meanings but I didn't find any. Those words which came to my mind have in my opinion a distinction. For instance, *washed* and *washy*.

Even though the quotes from the articles give the appearance that they are identical, is there any subtle distinction between *blurry* and *blurred* or are they interchangeable without changing any connotation?

Comment: "Blurred" has the added connotation of the subject having it's outline or shape deliberately made not clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Blurry* can always be replaced by *blurred* (except in the word *blurry-eyed*), but not always vice versa.  IMO, *blurry*, for the most part, fits all three meanings of *blurred* in the OALD excerpt, not just the first.

However, *blurred* has another use which *blurry* doesn't duplicate, and the dictionary doesn't bring out (probably because it's hard to do without examples).  When *blurred* follows *is*, *was*, etc., (i.e. *the picture was blurred*), it can take a modifier or modifier phrase (e.g. *the picture was blurred **by the rain*** or the *picture was **badly** blurred*).  *Blurry* cannot be used nearly as extensively in this way.

To go into nuances, even in the places where *blurry* and *blurred* are interchangeable, *blurred* suggests a previous state of non-blurriness and may suggest a perpetrator, whereas *blurry* only reports the state of the object and doesn't connote much more.  The distinction is, however, only slightly observed in common usage.

Comment: have knocked out the comment because it no longer adds anything. The rest of your answer is fully-focussed and not even slightly blurry/blurred (or is that an artifact of my excellent sharp-pixelled monitor? :)

Comment: ...actually, *blurred eyes* doesn't grate on me, and checking Google Books I find it's [not uncommon](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22blurred+eyes%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: You're right.  I must be too tired to post answers :/

Comment: Having mused on OP's point about most *adjective-derived-from-noun* and *past-participle-verb* pairs having different meanings, I wonder if your final paragraph embodies any "generic" principle, where no other factors come into play. How does it play out with things like *squashy/squashed, minty/minted, speckly/speckled, grainy/grained*, etc.?

Comment: *"The picture was **hopelessly** blurry"* sounds fine to me. I think you're actually on very sticky ground trying to identify too many "ways" one or the other word can't be used - a lot of them will turn out to be highly-specific idiomatic usages.

Answer (score 1):

Blurry is an adjective and does not have any particular implications as to why the image is indistinct, and will usually appear in the attributive and predicative positions:

- The image is blurry.
- The blurry image is useless.

Blurred is a participle and has additional usages available, and is more likely to occur in apposition. It has different shades of meaning too in that there is the more direct implication that it is the result of some (defective) blurring process as it derives from a verb. While an adjective can be used as a noun, this is slightly more common with a participle (which can in general be used as part of a compound verb, as an gerundive, or as a gerund). The point is not so much that 'blurry' couldn't substitute in all but the first of the examples below, but that we are talking about the result of a process (accidental in general, but deliberate in the case of the last one where 'blurry' would apply it was unintended). In the case of a photo of Doris Day, where photos of the actress were deliberately blurred to create a softer feel, we would not have 'blurry' as an option in examples 3 and 4 either.

- The ink has blurred.
- The photo, blurred as it was, was enough to recognize him.
- Do you want the one that was in focus or the one that was blurred.
- I prefer the blurred (one).
- The visible faces are the lawyers, the blurred are the accused.